# Pandas apply method | String recognised as a float

Tags: python, pandas

I have to retreat a dataframe's column where all observations contain the same type of value, a `string` as follows :

```
'Total: 1'
'Total: 1'
'Total: 2'
etc.
```

Then I try to run the apply method like this to the column `evolLevel` which contains those strings :

```
df['evolLevel'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

However it returns me the following error although this is still a `string` variable :

```
'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I've also tried to specify `axis=1` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I do no get any error when I run the code you are running. It works just fine (even `axis=1` is not needed).

Comment: Try `df['evolLevel'].str[-1]`.

Comment: That's weird, but if finally works if y do df['evolLevel'] = df['evolLevel'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-1])

Comment: @GaëtanLF Try my answer. That should work too.

Comment: @MayankPorwal no it won't, if the column contains a `float` object it will fail in exactly the same way

Comment: @GaëtanLF that means your column has a `float` object in it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are right. Let me remove my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom it may be interesting, it finally worked when I did :

```
df['evolLevel'] = df['evolLevel'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-1])
```